# How do you generally deal with topology?

Tags: topology

Especially around the eyes, mouth and hands

Comment: http://topologyguides.com

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=face+topology&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj18qP8orfZAhVns1QKHU0GCI0QsAQIKA&biw=1920&bih=1014

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&biw=1920&bih=1014&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=QKiNWrz2EuXn0gKZkJn4Bw&q=face+topology+edge+flow&oq=face+topology+edge+flow&gs_l=psy-ab.3...12276.17293.0.17494.12.11.1.0.0.0.120.943.10j1.11.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.119...0j0i30k1.0.lAfZSaHhh-I

Comment: Do a search for edge flow. Here's a video to get started with: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lip59doQQRk

Answer (score 1):

Something like this for the head:

[image]

And this for the hands:
[image]